# OpenCV3.0: SURF detection and FlannBased matcher tracking rectangle issue

Tags: opencv3.0, surf, flannbasedmatcher

I am trying to implement SURF detection and tracking using FlannBased matcher. 
My code is working properly for detection part but the issue is with tracking.

[image]

You can see in the above image the tracking rectangle is not focusing on the right object. And moreover the rectangle stays static even when i move my camera around. I am not sure where am i going wrong.

Here is the code i have implemented

```
void surf_detection::surf_detect(){

UMat img_extractor, snap_extractor;

if (crop_image_.empty())
    cv_snapshot.copyTo(dst);
else
    crop_image_.copyTo(dst);
//dst = QImagetocv(crop_image_);

imshow("dst", dst);

Ptr<SURF> detector = SURF::create(minHessian);
Ptr<DescriptorExtractor> extractor = SURF::create(minHessian);

cvtColor(dst, src, CV_BGR2GRAY);
cvtColor(frame, gray_image, CV_BGR2GRAY);


detector->detect(src, keypoints_1);
//printf("Object: %d keypoints detected\n", (int)keypoints_1.size());
detector->detect(gray_image, keypoints_2);
//printf("Object: %d keypoints detected\n", (int)keypoints_1.size());

extractor->compute(src, keypoints_1, img_extractor);
// printf("Object: %d descriptors extracted\n", img_extractor.rows);
extractor->compute(gray_image, keypoints_2, snap_extractor);

std::vector<Point2f> scene_corners(4);
std::vector<Point2f> obj_corners(4);

obj_corners[0] = (cvPoint(0, 0));
obj_corners[1] = (cvPoint(src.cols, 0));
obj_corners[2] = (cvPoint(src.cols, src.rows));
obj_corners[3] = (cvPoint(0, src.rows));

vector<DMatch> matches;
matcher.match(img_extractor, snap_extractor, matches);

double max_dist = 0; double min_dist = 100;

//-- Quick calculation of max and min distances between keypoints
for (int i = 0; i < img_extractor.rows; i++)
{
    double dist = matches[i].distance;
    if (dist < min_dist) min_dist = dist;
    if (dist > max_dist) max_dist = dist;
}
//printf("-- Max dist : %f \n", max_dist);
//printf("-- Min dist : %f \n", min_dist);

vector< DMatch > good_matches;

for (int i = 0; i < img_extractor.rows; i++)
{
    if (matches[i].distance <= max(2 * min_dist, 0.02))
    {
        good_matches.push_back(matches[i]);
    }
}

UMat img_matches;
drawMatches(src, keypoints_1, gray_image, keypoints_2,
    good_matches, img_matches, Scalar::all(-1), Scalar::all(-1),
    vector<char>(), DrawMatchesFlags::NOT_DRAW_SINGLE_POINTS);

if (good_matches.size() >= 4){

    for (int i = 0; i<good_matches.size(); i++){

        //get the keypoints from good matches
        obj.push_back(keypoints_1[good_matches[i].queryIdx].pt);
        scene.push_back(keypoints_2[good_matches[i].trainIdx].pt);

    }
}

H = findHomography(obj, scene, CV_RANSAC);

perspectiveTransform(obj_corners, scene_corners, H);

line(img_matches, scene_corners[0], scene_corners[1], Scalar(0, 255, 0), 4);

line(img_matches, scene_corners[1], scene_corners[2], Scalar(0, 255, 0), 4);

line(img_matches, scene_corners[2], scene_corners[3], Scalar(0, 255, 0), 4);

line(img_matches, scene_corners[3], scene_corners[0], Scalar(0, 255, 0), 4);

imshow("Good matches", img_matches);



}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your matches are *correct*, you are simply displaying them *wrong*. Matches refers to the `gray_image` coordinate system, but you're displaying them in the `img_matches` coordinate system.

So, basically, you need to translate them by the `src` width:

```
line(img_matches, scene_corners[0] + Point2f(src.cols,0), scene_corners[1] + Point2f(src.cols,0), Scalar(0, 255, 0), 4);
line(img_matches, scene_corners[1] + Point2f(src.cols,0), scene_corners[2] + Point2f(src.cols,0), Scalar(0, 255, 0), 4);
line(img_matches, scene_corners[2] + Point2f(src.cols,0), scene_corners[3] + Point2f(src.cols,0), Scalar(0, 255, 0), 4);
line(img_matches, scene_corners[3] + Point2f(src.cols,0), scene_corners[0] + Point2f(src.cols,0), Scalar(0, 255, 0), 4);
```

See also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33793149/5008845) related answer.

Comment: it throws error: 
binary '+': no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'cv::Point_<float>' (or there is no acceptable conversion)

Comment: i tried but now it draws something like a tick mark not a rectangle. No idea why.

Comment: Check now... :D Sorry but I don't have time to setup all and test it. Now it should work